# Python 3 regex multiple substitution in a file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use regex to substitute the found number in a file to a word instead. Example: "1" to "One". So far, I have the expression to substitute the found number, but once I try to replace multiple numbers it prints the file multiple times incorrectly. I've just started coding with python and regular expressions so, sorry if my code is complete wrong and awkward.

```
import re

def convertEnglish(filename):
f = open(filename)
for line in f:
    print(re.sub('1', 'One', line))
    print(re.sub('2', 'Two', line))
    print(re.sub('3', 'Three', line))

convertEnglish("Number_example.txt")
```

This is my output:

One 2 3 o'clock.

1 Two 3 o'clock.

1 2 Three o'clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.sub` does not change the string in-place, but it returns substituted string. Chain the return value of each substitution with next substitution to get what you want:

```
import re

def convertEnglish(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = re.sub('1', 'One', line)
            line = re.sub('2', 'Two', line)
            line = re.sub('3', 'Three', line)
            print line
```

BTW, `1` can match `1` in `12` resulting `one2`; `onetwo`. If that is not what you want, you can use `\b` (word boundary):

```
line = re.sub(r'\b1\b', 'One', line)
line = re.sub(r'\b2\b', 'Two', line)
line = re.sub(r'\b3\b', 'Three', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `re.sub function for this.`This way you can create a mapping as well in dictionary and match a `key` an return its `value`.

```
import re

def repl(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(1)=="1":
        return "One"
    elif matchobj.group(1)=="2":
         return "Two"
    #create a dictioanry of mappings and then match and send corresponding keys .
def convertEnglish(filename):
f = open(filename)
for line in f:
    line=re.sub(r'(\d+)', repl, line)

convertEnglish("Number_example.txt")
```